# How to disable starting MySQL service on Windows7 startup?

Tags: mysql, windows

When I turn on my desktop (Windows 7 SP1), I often find 2 or 3 GB of memory is already occupied by MySQL processes. I don't care about how much memory a database requires, if it actually runs some queries, but I do, if it's an app I even don't start myself yet. For that matter, I barely use MySQL barring when I develop some web apps in my local environments.

[image]

So is it possible to stop this gluttony? I tried to remove MySQL from my startup group via`msconfig`, but couldn't find its name over there.

Here is extra info.

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.15, for Win64 (x86_64)
MySQL Server 5.6
MySQL Workbench 6.0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable MySQL service from the Command Line (make sure you Run it as Administrator).

To disable service start on Windows startup (this will not stop the service if it is currently running):

```
sc config mysql start = manual
```

To stop the service:

```
net stop mysql
```

Comment: Thanks. Your command certainly seems to work, according to http://www.windows-commandline.com/start-stop-enable-disable-mysql-service .

Comment: If you get a 'The service name is invalid.' error, your service might be named something else. Type 'net start' to locate it. Mine was MySQL56, so the command to run to stop it was 'net stop mysql56'.

Comment: does not work as of november 28, 2022

Answer (score 22):

In Control panel open Administrative tools then double click **Services**.  Scroll down to MySQL and double click to open the properties.  Change the Startup type to Manual.

[image]

Comment: For reference, here was what I did. It appears I can't really select `start= manual` but any of options listed below. start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled|delayed-auto> So I went with `start= demand`.

Comment: works as of november 28, 2022